# Regex to match content between curly braces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following textfile and need to extract the text from the Element and Cluster matches. I'm using the following regular expression:

```
CLUSTER\[at....\][\d\D]+?{[\d\D]+?items[\d\D]+?}|(ELEMENT\[at....\][\d\D]+?}[\d\D]+?})
```

While this works fine, for some particular textfiles like this one below, where some elements will have more than one `DV` match, it won't extract the entire value matches section only the first element.

For example `ELEMENT[at0030]` will leave out the `DV_TEXT` matches and `DV_PROPORTION` matches while `ELEMENT[at0028]` will match everything I need.

I need my regular expression to be able to get everything inside the "value matches" curly braces of each `ELEMENT` not just the first value from here. Any help?

Down here is an example of a textfile I'm working on:

```
definition
    CLUSTER[at0000] matches {    -- Examination of a cleavage-stage embryo
        items cardinality matches {1..*; unordered} matches {
            ELEMENT[at0028] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Number of cells
                value matches {
                    DV_COUNT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0030] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Fragmentation
                value matches {
                    DV_CODED_TEXT matches {
                        defining_code matches {
                            [local::
                            at0031,    -- None
                            at0032,    -- Mild fragmentation
                            at0033,    -- Moderate fragmentation
                            at0034]    -- Severe fragmentation
                        }
                    }
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                    DV_PROPORTION matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0035] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Blastomere size
                value matches {
                    DV_CODED_TEXT matches {
                        defining_code matches {
                            [local::
                            at0036,    -- Equal, stage specific
                            at0037,    -- Unequal, stage specific
                            at0053,    -- Equal, non-stage specific
                            at0054]    -- Unequal, non-stage specific
                        }
                    }
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0038] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Nucleation
                value matches {
                    DV_CODED_TEXT matches {
                        defining_code matches {
                            [local::
                            at0039,    -- No visible nuclei
                            at0040,    -- Mononucleation
                            at0041,    -- Binucleation
                            at0051,    -- Multinucleation
                            at0052]    -- Broad multinucleation
                        }
                    }
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0042] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Cytoplasmic morphology
                value matches {
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0043] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Spatial distribution of cells
                value matches {
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0044] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Compaction
                value matches {
                    DV_CODED_TEXT matches {
                        defining_code matches {
                            [local::
                            at0045,    -- None
                            at0046,    -- Minimal
                            at0047,    -- Moderate
                            at0048]    -- Complete
                        }
                    }
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0049] occurrences matches {0..*} matches {    -- Other morphological features
                value matches {
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0055] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Morphology grade
                value matches {
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
        }
    }


ontology
    term_definitions = <
        ["en"] = <
            items = <
                ["at0000"] = <
                    text = <"Examination of a cleavage-stage embryo">
                    description = <"Morphological findings obtained by microscopy of the human cleavage-stage embryo.">
                >
                ["at0028"] = <
                    text = <"Number of cells">
                    description = <"Number of cells in a cleavage-stage embryo.">
                >
                ["at0030"] = <
                    text = <"Fragmentation">
                    description = <"Cytoplasmic fragmentation in a cleavage-stage embryo.">
                    comment = <"The proportion data type can be used to record a more precise assessment.">
                >
                ["at0031"] = <
                    text = <"None">
                    description = <"Absence of cytoplasmic fragments.">
                >
                ["at0032"] = <
                    text = <"Mild fragmentation">
                    description = <"Cytoplasmic fragments cover < 10% of the total cytoplasmic volume.">
                >
                ["at0033"] = <
                    text = <"Moderate fragmentation">
                    description = <"Cytoplasmic fragments cover 10 - 25% of the total cytoplasmic volume.">
                >
```

Comment: on a general note, you really shouldn't parse formal languages with regexes.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```js
const rx = /(?<=ELEMENT\[at\d{4}\] occurrences[^\n]+\n( +)value matches \{)[\d\D]+?\n\1(?=\})/g;

console.log(text.match(rx));
```

The basic idea is to solve the problem of having to count opening and closing curly braces by instead capturing the number of spaces after a newline and before `"value matches"` using the pattern`\n( +)value matches` and then matching everything until there is a newline followed by the same number of spaces and a curly brace, `\n\1\}`.

Is that clear?

---

'Proof' that it does work:

```js
const text = `
definition
    CLUSTER[at0000] matches {    -- Examination of a cleavage-stage embryo
        items cardinality matches {1..*; unordered} matches {
            ELEMENT[at0028] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Number of cells
                value matches {
                    DV_COUNT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0030] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Fragmentation
                value matches {
                    DV_CODED_TEXT matches {
                        defining_code matches {
                            [local::
                            at0031,    -- None
                            at0032,    -- Mild fragmentation
                            at0033,    -- Moderate fragmentation
                            at0034]    -- Severe fragmentation
                        }
                    }
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                    DV_PROPORTION matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0035] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Blastomere size
                value matches {
                    DV_CODED_TEXT matches {
                        defining_code matches {
                            [local::
                            at0036,    -- Equal, stage specific
                            at0037,    -- Unequal, stage specific
                            at0053,    -- Equal, non-stage specific
                            at0054]    -- Unequal, non-stage specific
                        }
                    }
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0038] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Nucleation
                value matches {
                    DV_CODED_TEXT matches {
                        defining_code matches {
                            [local::
                            at0039,    -- No visible nuclei
                            at0040,    -- Mononucleation
                            at0041,    -- Binucleation
                            at0051,    -- Multinucleation
                            at0052]    -- Broad multinucleation
                        }
                    }
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0042] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Cytoplasmic morphology
                value matches {
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0043] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Spatial distribution of cells
                value matches {
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0044] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Compaction
                value matches {
                    DV_CODED_TEXT matches {
                        defining_code matches {
                            [local::
                            at0045,    -- None
                            at0046,    -- Minimal
                            at0047,    -- Moderate
                            at0048]    -- Complete
                        }
                    }
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0049] occurrences matches {0..*} matches {    -- Other morphological features
                value matches {
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
            ELEMENT[at0055] occurrences matches {0..1} matches {    -- Morphology grade
                value matches {
                    DV_TEXT matches {*}
                }
            }
        }
    }


ontology
    term_definitions = <
        ["en"] = <
            items = <
                ["at0000"] = <
                    text = <"Examination of a cleavage-stage embryo">
                    description = <"Morphological findings obtained by microscopy of the human cleavage-stage embryo.">
                >
                ["at0028"] = <
                    text = <"Number of cells">
                    description = <"Number of cells in a cleavage-stage embryo.">
                >
                ["at0030"] = <
                    text = <"Fragmentation">
                    description = <"Cytoplasmic fragmentation in a cleavage-stage embryo.">
                    comment = <"The proportion data type can be used to record a more precise assessment.">
                >
                ["at0031"] = <
                    text = <"None">
                    description = <"Absence of cytoplasmic fragments.">
                >
                ["at0032"] = <
                    text = <"Mild fragmentation">
                    description = <"Cytoplasmic fragments cover < 10% of the total cytoplasmic volume.">
                >
                ["at0033"] = <
                    text = <"Moderate fragmentation">
                    description = <"Cytoplasmic fragments cover 10 - 25% of the total cytoplasmic volume.">
                >
`;

const rx = /(?<=ELEMENT\[at\d{4}\] occurrences[^\n]+\n( +)value matches \{)[\d\D]+?\n\1(?=\})/g;

const match = text.match(rx);

if (match != null) {
  match.forEach((m, i) => console.log(`${i}: ${m}`));
}
```

The above matches *everything inside the "value matches" curly braces of each ELEMENT* as requested. If you don't want any leading or trailing whitespace you could adapt the regex accordingly, for example:

```js
const rx = /(?<=ELEMENT\[at\d{4}\] occurrences[^\n]+\n( +)value matches \{\s*)\S+[\s\S]*?(?=\s*\n\1\})/g;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @MrSafira13 Added proof that it *does* work.

Comment: Oh nevermind you're right. I tried it on the regex101.com website and for some reason it didn't seem to be working. This works great thank you.